# How To Query Opportunity History Object in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, report, dashboard, apex, soql

We have opportunity History report type in salesforce Reports & Dashboard where we can use fields like "From Stage" & "To Stage". How can we use those two fields in SOQL? I tried but there is no such field on "Opportunity History" object. Is there any workaround for the same? (Need to use this in SOQL only no custom coding)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the From and To values, you need to query `OpportunityFieldHistory`.

```
SELECT CreatedDate, OldValue, NewValue 
FROM OpportunityFieldHistory 
WHERE opportunityid = 'yourid' AND Field = 'StageName' 
ORDER BY createddate
```